# How to transpose multiple columns to be in one column in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to transpose 3 columns to be in a new column. My data is similar to:

```
id   stage   A   B   C
1     p      0   2   1
2     q      0   1   3
```

and I expected to be like:

```
id   stage  type  value
1     p      A     0
1     p      B     2
1     p      C     1
2     q      A     0
2     q      B     1
2     q      C     3
```

I try to use df.melt but it does not give the result I want.
How can I do this with python?
Thank you.

Comment: What about `melt` did return expected results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `df.melt`:

```
In [1421]: df.melt(id_vars=['id', 'stage'], var_name='type', value_name='value')
Out[1421]: 
   id stage type  value
0   1     p    A      0
1   2     q    A      0
2   1     p    B      2
3   2     q    B      1
4   1     p    C      1
5   2     q    C      3
```

Answer (score 0):

`melt` does work

```
df.melt(['id','stage']).sort_values('stage')
```

Out:

```
   id stage variable  value
0   1     p        A      0
2   1     p        B      2
4   1     p        C      1
1   2     q        A      0
3   2     q        B      1
5   2     q        C      3
```